# Generate Parentheses Unique Solution fix

Tags: algorithm, stack

I was trying to solve this leetcode 22 problem: Generate parentheses with a given number n. I know there are other ways to solve the problem; I just want to know why mathematically my algorithm don't work.

I'm trying to place the left open parenthesis in every valid position by swapping it with the right parenthesis until the string `((()))` gets to `()()()`. It works for up to 3 but not above.

```cpp
vector<string> generateParenthesis(int n) {

    vector<string> fin;
    string baseString = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        baseString = "(" + baseString + ")";
    }
    fin.push_back(baseString);

    for(int l = n - 1; l > 0; l--) {
        int r = n;
        while (r < baseString.size() - 1) {
            // cout << "something";
            string cst = baseString;
            char temp = cst[r];
            cst[r] = cst[l];
            cst[l] = temp;
            r++;
            fin.push_back(cst);
        }
    }

    return fin;
}
```

Can anybody explain why it couldn't generate all combinations, and if it can be extended to do so?

Comment: Consider posting here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm cannot work correctly for larger  because in every iteration of the inner loop the `cst` string is only one swap different from `baseString`, and that `baseString` never changes after it has been built in the first loop.

So for instance, for =4, `baseString` will be set to `(((())))`. The algorithm will not be able to produce `()()()()` because that would require at least **two** swaps when starting from `baseString`.

Another way to see why it cannot work is that the number of created strings is 1 + (─1)², while the expected number of strings is , i.e. the [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics).

Comment: You're exactly right and I found that after posting it in a while too. Thought about how I can like detect if more than one swap is needed but it just seems to complicate the algorithm even more lol

Answer (score 0):

There is a general pattern for generating a wide variety of different kinds of sequences in lexical order:

Given the "current item", you can always make the next item with these 2 steps:

1. Increment the rightmost character that can be greater than the corresponding character in the current item. This works because the next item must be greater and, given that, must share the longest possible prefix in common with the current item.  If there is no such character, then you've already generated all items. Then
2. Set the remaining characters to the lowest possible value, because otherwise you'd be skipping some items instead of getting the next one.

So lets apply this to get all balanced bracket sequences from `((()))` to `()()()`:

1. Find the rightmost `(` that can change to `)`.  That's the last open with a greater number of preceding opens than closes.  Starting with `((()))` we get `(()...`, for example.
2. Then add the required number of opens and closes after it, with the opens first.  That gives us `(()())`

Let's do it again: `(()())` -> `(())...` -> `(())()`

`(())()` -> `()...` -> `()(())`

`()(())` -> `()()...` -> `()()()`

`()()()` -> done

In C++ it looks like this:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    const int N = 6;
    std::string str;
    int opens = 0, closes = 0;
    do {
        for (;opens < N; ++opens) {
            str += '(';
        }
        for (;closes < N; ++closes) {
            str += ')';
        }
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
        
        // find the open to swap
        while(str.size() > 0) {
            char c = str.back();
            str.pop_back();
            if (c==')') {
                --closes;
            } else {
                --opens;
                if (opens > closes) {
                    str += ')';
                    ++closes;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } while (!str.empty());
    return 0;
}
```

[Try it on ideone](https://ideone.com/iicRkY)